# When updating a widget instance programmatically, layout updates are removed

Tags: magento-1.9, bug, widget-instance

I tried to update a widget instance as follows (where `/PATH/TO` and `WIDGET_INSTANCE_ID` should be replaced by the actual values:

```
require_once '/PATH/TO/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$widgetInstance = Mage::getModel('widget/widget_instance');
$widgetInstance->load(WIDGET_INSTANCE_ID);
$widgetInstance->setData('title', 'foo');
$widgetInstance->save();
```

After executing this code, all layout updates of the widget have been removed.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 5):

The cause of this issue is that the format of the `page_groups` field needs a different format for saving than is used available after loading.

The format needed for saving can be generated from the format after loading by placing the following code somewhere between the `load` and `save` calls:

```
if ($widgetInstance->getData('page_groups')) {
    $formattedPageGroups = [];
    foreach ($widgetInstance->getData('page_groups') as $pageGroup) {
        $pageGroupName = $pageGroup['page_group'];
        $formattedPageGroups[] = [
            'page_group' => $pageGroupName,
            $pageGroupName => [
                'page_id' => $pageGroup['page_id'],
                'layout_handle' => $pageGroup['layout_handle'],
                'for' => $pageGroup['page_for'],
                'block' => $pageGroup['block_reference'],
                'entities' => $pageGroup['entities'],
                'template' => $pageGroup['page_template']
            ]
        ];
    }
    $widgetInstance->setData('page_groups', $formattedPageGroups);
}
```

Note that this is in essence the same issue as described in the [post on copying a widget instance](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5832/copy-a-widget-instance-programmatically-preserving-layout-updates).

Comment: Saved my day ! thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I think the name of the property is `'page_template'` and not `'template'` at line:

`'template' => $pageGroup['template']`

should be

`'template' => $pageGroup['page_template']`

Comment: You're right, this was an error in the sample code. I have now changed this in my answer. Thanks for reporting this.